# Installed Win7 after Ubuntu, Win removed Ubuntu boot option

Tags: ubuntu, boot, windows

Completely 100% new to Linux.

I recently partitioned my drive to run Windows and Ubuntu simultaneously. Ubuntu installed fine, but then I installed Win7 and suddenly Ubuntu disappeared from the boot options.

This is probably semi-duplicate, but the answers to the other questions insinuated there was something wrong with "GRUB" something. The suggested solution seemed to depend on the Linux terminal. Maybe I'm missing something trivial, but I don't see how I access the terminal at this point. Can I fix it via Windows somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows installation process overwrites GRUB. And because the Windows bootloader (at least when compared to GRUB) isn't particularly good, it can't boot GNU/Linux.

Therefore, boot into an Ubuntu live cd and use the terminal to (re)install GRUB. I'll leave this as an exercise for you to research, but if you need help, come back here and ask a new question.

Comment: As an aside, always install Windows first, if at all possible. Saves a lot of headaches.